# What Al Bhed primers are missable?

Tags: final-fantasy-10

I want to try and get all the primers on one play through. What, if any, Al Bhed Primers are missable?

Answer (score 4):

Most of the missable ones are in the Al Bhed Home during the storyline apart from one in Bevelle.

**Al Bhed Home: Outside:**
Just when you head towards the Al Bhed home it's in some rubble on the left hand side

**Al Bhed Home: Quarters:**
When you are inside the home, you will come to a thin corridor and you'll notice the camera changes to a different angle. Keep moving forward until it goes back to normal, then go back the way you came. You'll see a door on your left. Enter it. After a fight check on the bed in the room for the primer.

**Al Bhed Home: Hallway:**
Same thin corridor as the last one. As you move forwards, the path will fork into three directions. Head to the right path and you'll see it on the ground in the far corner at the back.

**Bevelle Temple: Pre-Cloister of Trials:**
At the point where the story takes you to Bevelle and direct you towards the Cloister of Trials, you'll notice an area with a set of stairs. This one is on the ground just to the right or left of those stairs.